# How to ignore some commands from command handler help command?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Following the guide at [the discord js guide][1] I managed to make the dynamic help command. Now, when I run the help command, it does list all the commands, but I want it to hide some that include `ownerOnly: true` in the command file. Right now, when ownerOnly is true, only the bot owner(s) can execute that command, however it still shows up in the help command. Here is the help command I used:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'help', //command name
    description: 'Lists commands or gets info about a specific command.',
    usage: `(command name)`,
    guildOnly: false,
//  ownerOnly: true,      this is where I would put the ownerOnly thing.
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message, args, prefix) { //inside here command stuff
        const data = [];
        const { commands } = message.client;

        if (!args.length) {
            data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join('\n'));
            data.push(`\n**\nYou can send \`${prefix}help [command name]\` to get info on a specific command!`);
            const helpembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Here's a list of all my commands:")
            .setDescription('**' + data, { split: true})
            .setColor('RANDOM')

            return message.author.send(helpembed)
            .then(() => {
            if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
            message.react('');
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
            message.reply('it seems like I can\'t DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?');
        });
        }
        const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
        const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));

        if (!command) {
            return message.reply('that\'s not a valid command!');
        }

        if (command.aliases) data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
        if (command.description) data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
        if (command.usage) data.push(`**Usage:** ${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`);
        data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown || 3} second(s)`);

        const helpembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Name: ${command.name}`)
        .setDescription(data, { split: true})
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        message.channel.send(helpembed)
    },
};
```

and the command handler:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName))
command.execute(message, args, prefix, client);
```

I want the help command to ignore the commands with `ownerOnly: true` in it, any ideas?

Edit: The owner only commands are stored in a separate category/folder if that helps.
[1]: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#a-dynamic-help-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```js
            data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join('\n'));
```

Can have a `.filter()` added before the `.map()` and filter it any way you want. This isn't a discord.js thing, just a [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) thing. Try

```js
            data.push(commands.filter(command => !command.ownerOnly).map(command => command.name).join('\n'));
```

and let us know whether that works for you. Note that it doesn't stop people from guessing the command and asking for that command's help explicitly, or trying to use it; it only filters the array that gets listed to exclude items with a truthy `ownerOnly` attribute.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! I can probably implement something like this to disallow guessing as well.